# AngularJS how to send multipart/mixed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am working on a project where I have to upload a small bit of JSON with a file, working in AngularJS.

I've written code using Danial Farid's angular-file-upload, and it is working, except, it always sends "multipart/form-data, boundary=<whatever>"

However, I *MUST* use multipart/mixed.

This is my call:

```
$scope.upload = $upload.upload({
  url: <my url>,
  method: 'POST',
  data: $scope.data,
        file: file,
}).progress(function(evt) {
  console.log('percent: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // file is uploaded successfully
  console.log(data);
});
```

Is there a way to modify the headers just before it gets sent?

If not using his angular-file-upload, then by another method, hopefully without having to 'roll my own' function?

Edit 1:

I just cannot understand how it can be so difficult to make this change.  Of course you can add

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed'}
```

But this does absolutely NOTHING because there is no boundary.  Why can't there be a way to pull the boundary out?  Something like

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed, boundary=%b'}
```

I need to get this working ASAP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't wait any longer.  I ended up rolling my own and it does work.  Here's the code...hopefully others can benefit.

file_contents is the output from reader.readAsArrayBuffer($scope.files[0]);

You need to build up a blob from the preamble text, the file data and the footer, because otherwise appending binary data to a string will do conversions on the binary file data and it will not work properly.

```
var epochTicks = 621355968000000000;
var ticksPerMillisecond = 10000;
var yourTicks = epochTicks + ((new Date).getTime() * ticksPerMillisecond);

var boundary='---------------------------'+yourTicks;

var header="--"+boundary+"\r\n";

var footer="\r\n--"+boundary+"--\r\n";

var contenttype="multipart/mixed; boundary="+boundary;

var contents=header+"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"json\"\r\n";
contents+="Content-Type: application/json\r\n";
contents+="Content-Length: "+JSON.stringify(data).length+"\r\n\r\n";
contents+=JSON.stringify(data)+"\r\n";

contents+=header+"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\""+$scope.files[0].name+"\"\r\n";
contents+="Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";
contents+="Content-Type: "+$scope.files[0].type+"\r\n";
contents+="Content-Length: "+$scope.files[0].size+"\r\n\r\n";

blob=new Blob([contents,file_contents,footer]);

$http.post(restUrl+"user/avatar/uploadAvatar",blob,{'headers':{'Content-Type':contenttype}}).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("success!");
}).
error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  alert("failed!");
});
```

Comment: 100 thanks to you dude.. i have been trying this from 2-3weeks without luck, by trying your solution, got fixed in a single try...

Comment: i even posted a quetion too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31829025/content-type-for-json-and-audio-file

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help!

Comment: It does not work. I am trying to post IMAGE metainfo and image file can you help me ?

Comment: @RajenderSaini Can you post a plunker?  I'll try and see if I can help.

Comment: Jim - I am able move on with another work around. Thanks for help ! this solution really helped me to get started !!

Comment: A transformRequest could solve your problem with less code: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses

Comment: In [this article](http://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/) is explained how to solve it using a transformRequest method as suggested by ogaihtorecic